# WMI Scripting issues displaying multiple drive info

Tags: vbscript

Please note that I am a newbie in WMI, have been researching this issue for most of the day, and even though there are hundres of posts, I am struglling to find any help on this specific problem.

Experiencing an issues using Win32_DiskDrive - Caption and also name functions:
When I execute the VB.script:
           Try
                Dim connection As New ConnectionOptions
                connection.Username = userNameBox.Text
                connection.Password = passwordBox.Text
                connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:ms1"

```
            Dim scope As New ManagementScope( _
                "\\ms1\root\CIMV2", connection)
            scope.Connect()

            Dim query As New ObjectQuery( _
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive") 

            Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query) 

            For Each queryObj As ManagementObject in searcher.Get()

                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------")
                Console.WriteLine("Win32_DiskDrive instance")
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------")
                Console.WriteLine("Caption: {0}", queryObj("Caption"))
            Next
```

it correctly lists the 5 harddrives that I have in the server i am querying.

But when I execute it in asp.net (vb) it lists only the 1 drive.

```
    Dim query4 As New ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive")

    Dim searcher4 As New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query4)


    For Each queryObj3 As ManagementObject In searcher4.Get()

        'Availability

        ' text15.Text = queryObj3("Name")

        text16.Text = queryObj3("Caption")

    Next
```

My resuls are bountd to a textfield, formatted to wrap and multiline.

Regards

Louis van Rooyen

Comment: This is not VBScript. It has the 'As' keyword after Dim, which suggests its actually VB6 or something. Can you change the tags? :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you overrwrite `text16.Text` again and again, so the result in the end would be the information of the last device only.

Try concatenating the string instead:

```
' TODO: Use proper string formating instead of simpy string concatenating  '
text16.Text = text16.Text & queryObj3("Caption")
```